# Program received signal SIGABRT

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I working in iPhone application, i am picking an image from photo library using UIImage picker control, then processing it and displays the image and the corresponding output using UIImageview and UITextview respectively. For some images it working fine and for some of images program crashed and while checking this with break point i am getting message like PROGRAM RECEIVED SIGNAL SIGABRT. can any one suggest me how to handle this error.
Note: For every image i am getting output, i checked it with breakpoint.
my sample code is here,

To display image:

```
 CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 240.0f);
 UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];
 [myImage setImage:img];
 myImage.opaque = YES; // explicitly opaque for performance
 [self.view addSubview:myImage];
 [myImage release];
```

To display text:

```
 CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 250.0f, 320.0f,25.0f);
 UITextView * tmpTextView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
 tmpTextView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",@"value: ", somevalue];
 [self.view addSubview:tmpTextView];
 [tmpTextView release];
```

Comment: Could you edit your post to have the code with syntax highlighting?

Answer (score 15):

`SIGABRT` is raised by the [`abort(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/abort) function.  It's impossible to tell exactly what's going on in your program without more information, but the most common reasons that `abort()` gets called are:

- You're sending a message to an Objective-C object that doesn't support/implement that message.  This results in the dreaded ["unrecognized selector sent to instance"](https://www.google.com/search?q=unrecognized+selector+sent+to+instance+site%3Astackoverflow.com) error.
- You have a failed assertion somewhere.  In non-debug builds that define the macro `NDEBUG`, the standard library macro [`assert(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/assert) calls `abort()` when the assertion fails
- You have some memory stomping/allocation error.  When `malloc`/`free` detect a corrupted heap, the may call `abort()` (see, e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171194/getting-program-received-signalsigabrt-in-iphone-sdk))
- You're throwing an uncaught exception (either a C++ exception or an Objective-C exception)

In almost all cases, the debug console will give you a little more information about what's causing `abort()` to be called, so always take a look there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I fixed that problem.

Comment: @ashok : it would be much helpful if u tell us how did u solved that error.

Comment: A good way of finding the error partially in your own code base, is to turn on an exception break point (or make sure you don't have break points turned off :) ). This will show you for example exactly which one of your asserts is creating the issue.