# Performing segues depending on contents of textfield

Tags: segue, textfield

I just start learning code couple months ago. I Learned from watching YouTube tutorials and Reading some online notes. Here is my situation

I have 4 storyboards. 3 of which is connected to 1 of them by segue. I have identified each of my segues with names. In my first storyboard there are 2 textfields. I want to activate each segues depending on the contents of the 2 textfields. Am i doing it correctly?

This is my **ViewController.h**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *text1
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *text2
- (IBAction)buttonClick:(id)sender;
@end
```

And this is my **ViewController.m**

```
@synthesize text1 = _text1;
@synthesize text2 = _text2;

- (IBAction)buttonClick:(id)sender:
{
if((_text1.text = @"A")&&(_text2.text = @"B"))
{
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ab" sender:self];}
else if
((_text1.text = @"B")&&(_text2.text = @"C"))
{
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"bc" sender:self];}
else
{self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ca" sender:self];}
}
```

Am i doing it correctly? 
I came up with this myself so i am not sure if it works. 
Thanks!

Comment: Which programming language is this? Please [tag](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) your question, as it will help you to get an answer quicker.

Comment: why don't you run it in xCode? You should try out your code and put effort in it, then if you have some problems and you don't know what to do, ask about them here...

Answer (score 0):

you can trigger the segues programmatically like this(this is your own code with some corrections):

```
- (IBAction)buttonClick:(id)sender {
    if((self.text1.text == @"A") && (self.text2.text == @"B")) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ab" sender:self];
    } else if ((self.text1.text == @"B") && (self.text2.text == @"C")) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"bc" sender:self];
    } else {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ca" sender:self];
    }
}
```

instead of using the instance variables like `_text1` and `_text2` you should use the properties `self.text1`, etc.

Comment: Thanks Reza, I did what you suggested and manage to build my app without any issue. However when I added contents into the textfield and clicked my button, i had an error Thread 1: signal SIGBART. I notice alot of people have the same problem as me and have found solutions to their problems. However due to my lack of knowledge bout coding, i do not seem to understand this solutions. Could you help me once again?

Comment: @ChewAmos this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887609/program-received-signal-sigabrt

Comment: if you can provide me with some more information on your case I may be able to help you more accurately.