# signal sigabrt swift2 app crach

Tags: ios, swift

My app runs but when I test it I get program received signal “sigabrt” on main. Please help. Here is the custom part of my AppDelegate:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions )
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        return true
    }
}
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFvZE.jpg)

Comment: If it's running, the crash point is not actually in your AppDelegate, so you need to set a Swift breakpoint so it'll show you more info, or press the play button in debugger so that an actual crashlog will be generated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Program received signal SIGABRT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887609/program-received-signal-sigabrt)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you have an incorrect outlet. This means a view in your storyboard is thinking it is connected with your code but it is not. Remove the outlet then recreate it. Check out this [this resource](http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=MkcqBIS8Swc) for more on how to fix your outlet.